# AWS Lambda as a file verification system for s3 uploads

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I need to use s3 to store content from users and govern access, in a social network type of service.

So far this is what I have thought of doing:

1. Client tells LAMP server he wants to upload a file
2. LAMP authenticates, and generates a presigned url for s3 where user can upload. It also creates an encrypted version of that key using private key. Then it adds this key, along with the user who started it in a mysql table(along with when it was started)
3. LAMP then sends the key and the digital signature from 2. to client.
4. Client then uploads the file to s3
5. After finishing, he tells LAMP that that file was completed. It sends in the key and the digital signature.
6. LAMP makes sure both the key and the signature match. If they do, LAMP knows that the client is honest about the key being given to him(and he has not randomly generated it)
7. LAMP then checks s3 to make sure that the file with that key exists, if it does,then delete the row which was added in 2.

After asking around, I was told that it is not possible for s3 itself to verify that a file is a 'valid' file of a certain type(I want to enforce only images )
So I decided to use aws lambda to verify it(if its a 'wrong' file, just delete it) . Just after the file is uploaded to s3, lambda can be fired.

However, it is possible that BEFORE lambda finishes checking the file,step 7 above gets executed. This means my server will think file is valid.

Is there any way to make an s3 upload+lambda execution atomic ?
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Also , could anybody tell how much resources (and time in seconds) will verifying a file to check if its a valid image take if the image is valid? I expect average images to be of size <10 mb. If the time is quite less, I can tell lambda to update a db field (marking that file as 'checked'). My server will do long polling till then on that particular record